# Linking another HTML page ,when clicked a facebook share button

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Do anyone know how to make a facebook share button with 2 actions ? similar like this , I got a html page with an IQ question ,when you click to share and link to answer pages .

Here are the question page look like :
[image]

Here is the code of share button:

```
<a class="btn-u btn-u-lg btn-block btn-u-dark-blue" href="###" target="_blank">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</a>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116001/facebook-like-and-share-button-with-callback