# jQuery detecting button click in another window (different URL)

Tags: javascript, jquery

From my website, the user click on a share link. Then it opens the Facebook sharer in a new window using this URL: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=anyurl.com

There is possible to know if user clicks on SHARE button or just closed the sharer window? I know that is possible to check if window was closed, but there is possible to detect click button from another window using remote URL?

Thank you.

Comment: See if FaceBook share gives a callback, it would be easier.

Comment: i guess this is what you look for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116001/facebook-like-and-share-button-with-callback

Comment: I forgot to mention: I don't want to use an API key. By using the supplied sharer link I don't need an API key.

Comment: @PLazzo, it is recommended to use the  [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4). There you can specify more options, a URI to be redirected after share. You will need an app ID. I think it is the best way to go