# Get Facebook User ID or Name

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, api

I have share button on my website and now they can Share and it's show up like this

[image]

but what I want is to get User ID or Name when they have successful shared on their facebook.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116001/facebook-like-and-share-button-with-callback)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: see my answer. what would you do with the data anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to get any data of a user without authorizing that user. Users who shared something with your share button are completely anonymous.